# Firebase Verification SMS format is not recognized by One Time Code feature on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication

So in the Firebase templates we see the following SMS format:

> %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.

But I'm getting this:
[image]

And it seems like this SMS format is not recognizable by OneTimeCode feature on iOS

I saw testers reported this feature working, but they got valid sms format:
[image]

And the keyboard suggestions recognizes it:
[image]

I was digging some issues reported and in some ticket this was mentioned:

> I'd take a look at the format of your SMS as Apple has some specific requirements for "oneTimeCode" to work. I believe some of the
> requirements for the SMS are:
>
> must contain the words code, passcode, or verification number
>
> code must be numeric and between 3 and 8 digits without spaces
>
> must not be using a custom keyboard

So my sms format doesn't match the Firebase template and possible requirements for iOS feature to work.

Any ideas why? And why the format is different for users, what does it depend on?